# How do I transfer a cookie to a Netscape file using CURL PHP?

Tags: curl

There is a variable that stores cookies:

```
$cookie = 'session=123;gate=kUwp1keS7kmBjF0rQfEAKbbdR;id=3GYAN';
```

My task is that I need to write these cookies to a `Netscape HTTP Cookie File` using CURL. I do it like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
```

But nothing is written to the file. You have write rights, the path is correct. You probably can't just do that. How can I record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

curl won't write cookies to the file that it didn't receive in a response but you can simply write them to the file yourself so that curl will read them when using `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`.

The curl website describes the [cookie file format](https://curl.se/docs/http-cookies.html) it uses when saving cookies as:

> The cookie file format is text based and stores one cookie per line. Lines that start with # are treated as comments.
>
> Each line that each specifies a single cookie consists of seven text fields separated with TAB characters. A valid line must end with a newline character.
> Fields in the file
>
> Field number, what type and example data and the meaning of it:
>
> ```
> string example.com - the domain name`
> boolean FALSE - include subdomains
> string /foobar/ - path
> boolean TRUE - send/receive over HTTPS only
> number 1462299217 - expires at - seconds since Jan 1st 1970, or 0
> string person - name of the cookie
> string daniel - value of the cookie
> ```

Something like the following should work:

```
<?php

$cookieFile        = dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt';
$cookie            = 'session=123;gate=kUwp1keS7kmBjF0rQfEAKbbdR;id=3GYAN';
$domainName        = '.example.com'; // note leading '.'
$includeSubdomains = 'TRUE';
$path              = '/'; // path for cookies
$secure            = 'TRUE';
$expires           = 0;

$cookies = explode(';', $cookie);
foreach($cookies as $c) {
    list($name, $value) = explode('=', $c, 2);

    $line = sprintf(
        "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%d\t%s\t%s\n",
        $domainName,
        $includeSubdomains,
        $path,
        $secure,
        $expires,
        $name,
        $value
    );

    file_put_contents($cookieFile, $line, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Note: the code doesn't check to see if a cookie with the name already exists in the file.

Prior to making a request, write the cookies to the file with the above code and specify the file with `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` to instruct curl to load cookies from this file.